# data from socket doesn't show in view

Tags: angular, nativescript

I get data from socket io but doesn't show in view.

I have this function in ts:

```
   socketIO.on('hello', (data) => { 
            console.log('data', data);
            this.mydata= data; 
        });
```

Data in console show like this:

data {
  "nr": "123456789456"
 }

in htm Nativescript:

```
<StackLayout >
        <Label [text]='mydata'></Label>
</StackLayout>
```

How to display in view my data? In console data show correctly

Comment: I can see that `data` is JSON. You should convert it to string like `JSON.stringify(data)`. If it still not works, try this syntax `[(ngModel)]="mydata"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are running inside `ngZone`

```
....

constructor(private zone:NgZone) {
    super()
}

    ....
    socketIO.on('hello', (data) => { 
        this.zone.run(()=> {
           console.log('data', data);
           this.mydata= data;
        }); 
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have to trigger change detection after assignent
https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef#markforcheck

```
class componant {
  constructor(private cdf:ChangeDetectorRef){}

socketIO.on('hello', (data) => { 
            console.log('data', data);
            this.mydata= data; 
this.cdf.markForCheck()
        });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use binding like this -

```
<StackLayout >
        <Label text= {{ mydata }}></Label>
</StackLayout>
```

Let me know if it works.

For further reading [read docs here](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/ns-ui-widgets/label)

Comment: Doesn't show and like this binding. I put in my post and JSON data

Answer (score 0):

can you try like this

TS:

```
    mydata: any;
    const self = this;
    socketIO.on('hello', (data) => { 
        console.log('data', data);
        self.mydata= data; 
    });
```

HTML:

```
    <StackLayout>
       <Label [text]='mydata'></Label>
    </StackLayout>
```

let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

From console's output I see that `data` is an object. Shouldn't the `[text]` input on `<Label>` be a string?